# IL .Net: How to provide step over, step through debugger support for GOSUB

Tags: .net, attributes, il, basic

I've implemented a .Net version of a legacy Basic language using IL assembler. It's working just fine. However, there's an issue of how to provide a better debugging experience for the implementation of GOSUB statement in Visual Studio IDE. The GOSUB statement, common in Basic languages, is implemented as a branch into a section of code and a branch back. The issue is that both step into (F10) and step over (F11) behave the same -- both go into the GOSUB section. What is desired is that F10 step over the GOSUB statement while F11 goes in (current behavior).

What can I do to implement step over when user hits F10? Is there some attribute that I can take advantage of?

Comment: Can't you implement `GOSUB` as a method call? Because that's where Step into and Step over differ.

Comment: The semantics of GOSUB vs method call are too different. For example, they have different member scoping and error processing.  Maintaining compatibility with legacy apps is paramount. This goal has been achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Step-over requires an agreement between the debugger and debuggee. The standard agreement involves method calls and returns. Since you do not want to follow that agreement, you would need to form another. This probably means you would need to [implement your own debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397953%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), or if you are lucky, you might be able to achieve this with a [visual studio plugin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb161718.aspx). Either way, the compiler will undoubtedly need to record some metadata somewhere describing which branch instructions should be treated as GOTO's and what ranges of IL instructions would need to be skipped when performing such a step-over.